# LUIS built-in geography type sometimes recognizes a city, but other times doesn't

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I'm a bit confused. I'm using LUIS's built-in geographyV2 type.

My utterances are things like "are there any part time cashier positions near houston?" (recognized) or "do you have any part time cashier jobs within 10 miles of houston?" (not recognized).

[image]

[image]

If I hover over the unrecognized instance of "houston," I don't have the option to tag it as a geographyV2 instance (if I try "browse pre-built entities, it doesn't shown geographyV2, I guess since that is already one of my types).

[image]

Is there any way I can train it better to recognize houston in the 2nd case?

Seems like some cities don't get picked up at all:

[image]

While others are detected without a problem:

[image]

If you have any tips, please let me know. This is the first time I've used LUIS. Overall, I'm very impressed!

Thanks

---

Updates based on Steven's suggestions:

Now I'm able to get Anchorage and Houston recognized. But this introduces a problem with Los Angeles. It is getting extracted as two entities:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Similar issue for St. Louis (it wants to tokenize "St" and "Louis" separately).

Sorry for being such a n00b :-)

Comment: I tried repro'ing the issue and it does appear to be a bit buggy. I will notify the LUIS team and await a response. In the mean time, you can swap out the "geographyV2" prebuilt entity for the "Places.AbsoluteLocation" prebuilt domain entity. Docs show it can take a variety of address types including simple city names. I tested in an app using Anchorage, Houston, and Boise and it worked just fine. Be sure to include many example utterances so training is optimized. I'll update here when I hear from the LUIS team.

Comment: Me again. I swapped out geographyV2 for Places.AbsoluteLocation as you suggested. Now place names like Anchorage and Houston are recognized. I'm having a bit of trouble with place names like Los Angeles now. I tagged each word as the entity type and now it extracts two separate entities. I edited my question above to include images.

Comment: When you submit an utterance that has a multi-word name (like "Los Angeles"), it will default to assigning the first word to entity and ignore (usually) the second word. To correct, select the first word ("Los") and remove the label/entity. Next, click the first word followed by the second (i.e. one after the other, in succession). The words will now be surrounded by one set of brackets. That tells LUIS you want to assign an entity to the two words as one. Choose the entity you want in the floating menu and off you go!

Comment: Also, regarding the geographyV2 issue, LUIS uses Named Entity Recognizers (NER) which is managed by a seperate team. Subsequently, the LUIS team has no control over the quality of the output. The issue is noted, however.

Comment: Thanks again for the tips and advice!

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem regarding it recognizing some cities sometimes, and others not.  I tried the Places.AbsoluteLocation, but it still does not recognize some cities.

Comment: Yeah Latin America is not recognized whilst South America is recognized as geographyV2 - is this a bug ?

Comment: and whats a work around ?

Answer (score 0):

I have somewhat similar issue.  I have the utterance:

`"what is the price of diesel in Latin America"`

`Latin America` is not tagged as geographyV2!

I tried `Asia` and same thing!

I tried `North America`, `South America`, `South Africa`, `Middle East` and those worked and were tagged!

I wondered - why the inconsistency?

I looked over the docs and here is a suggestion:

`The behavior of prebuilt entities can't be modified but you can improve resolution by adding the prebuilt entity as a feature to a machine-learning entity or sub-entity.`

Here is the link : [LUIS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-entities)

Here is what I have come up with to resolve it:

[image]